# How to match route only if param is integer in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

For example this router

```
{
    path: '/client',
    component: ClientRootComponent,
    children: [
        {path: '', component: ClientListComponent},
        {path: ':clientId', component: ClientOpenComponent, resolve: makeResolver(ClientOpenResolver)}
    ]
},
{
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent
}
```

will pass both URLs */client/1234* and */client/asdf* to ClientOpenComponent. How I can make that */client/asdf* will be matched as NotFound and passed to NotFoundComponent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a custom matcher to your route

```ts
import { defaultUrlMatcher } from '@angular/router/src/shared';

function digitsMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[], segmentGroup: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route): UrlMatchResult | null {
  const result = defaultUrlMatcher(segments, segmentGroup, route);

  if (!result || !result.consumed || result.consumed.length < 1) {
    return;
  }

  const re = /^\d+$/;
  const match = re.exec(result.consumed[0].path);

  if (match) {
    return result;
  }

  return null;
}
```

```ts
{
    path: '/client',
    component: ClientRootComponent,
    children: [
        {path: '', component: ClientListComponent},
        {path: ':clientId', component: ClientOpenComponent, resolve: makeResolver(ClientOpenResolver), matcher: digitsMatcher}
    ]
},
{
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent
}
```

The code is not tested

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/73407351e7fa75250be8bdb6c1eb4f7d37f6f947/modules/%40angular/router/src/shared.ts#L39
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/UrlMatcher

Comment: The compiler yells at me if I try to `import { defaultUrlMatcher } from '@angular/router/src/shared';` I ended up having to copy/paste the Angular src for `defaultUrlMatcher` into my project because it's not part of the Angular router's public API.

Comment: It's still here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/shared.ts#L113 but the docs also don't list it. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Had to add a specific folder to the path, example: 
import { defaultUrlMatcher } from '@angular/router/esm2015/src/shared'; // options include esm5, esm2015, but the fesm folders do not support it. https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/5wdqcw/flat_ecmascript_modules/ . reason: "A flat ES Module is a bundled ES module that only exports the public API."

Comment: It seems this solution gives a runtime error now. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31862