# How to specity type for route parameter in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I have the following routes in an angular module

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  {path: '', component: AdminProductsComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'products', component: AdminProductsComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: "products/:id", component: AdminProductDetailsComponent },
  { path: "products/:id/edit", component: EditProductComponent },
  { path: "orders", component: AdminOrdersComponent },
  { path: "orders/:id", component: AdminOrderDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'products/new', component: NewProductComponent },
];
```

But whenever I navigate to /products/new in the browser, AdminProductDetailsComponent gets loaded with the id param set to 'new'. How can I specify that the :id param in the 'products/:id' path must be an integer

Comment: In Angular, the non-parameterized routes takes precedence over parameterized routes.

Comment: The order of the routes is important. The first matching route will be chosen, so given that `/products/new` matches the parameterized route, that'll be chosen in the above case. You'd want to put the 'products/new' route above the parameterized route.

Comment: Or you can add custom matcher for routes like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41543827/3955714

Answer (score 1):

You can check using `canActivate` for the route if the passed param is integer do your things else show an error message or re-route to proper path where you can feed correct information to the URL.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";

export class TestService implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
    ){

    }

    canActivate(
      next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean { 
           // here check the params
         const id = +next.paramMap.get('id') // we get it in string
         if (!isNan(id)) {
             return true;
         } else {
             // route it or do something you want
         }
      }

   
}
```

Add this guard to the route:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  {path: '', component: AdminProductsComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'products', component: AdminProductsComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: "products/:id", component: AdminProductDetailsComponent, canActivate: [TestService] },
  { path: "products/:id/edit", component: EditProductComponent },
  { path: "orders", component: AdminOrdersComponent },
  { path: "orders/:id", component: AdminOrderDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'products/new', component: NewProductComponent },
];
```

There could be other ways too, open for suggestion how we could do it better.

Answer (score 0):

how about child routes? Did you try it?

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'products', component: AdminProductsComponent, pathMatch: 'full',
        children: [
           { path: 'new', component: NewProductComponent },
           { path: ":id", component: AdminProductDetailsComponent },
           { path: ":id/edit", component: EditProductComponent  },
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter type can be verified in the [canMatch](https://angular.io/api/router/CanMatchFn) property for the route. If this property returns true this means the route is activated/selected otherwise the route is ignored and the next one in order is considered.

```
const canMatchEdit: CanMatchFn = (route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]) {
let id=segments[[1]].path;
return !IsNaN(Number(id));
}

{
  path: 'product/:id',
  component: Component,
  canMatch: [canMatchEdit],
},
```